# Final condition continues to fire regardless of argument passed

Tags: python, string

I have the lines below:

```
text = str("")

while text != "q" or "quit":
    print 

    print("             Select from the following menu")
    print("             A. Add Employee")
    print("             B. Remove Employee")
    print("             C. Find Employee")
    print("             D. Display the current directory")
    print("             Q. Quit")
    text = str.lower(input("Enter your selection: "))
    print("Current selection is ", text)

    if text == "a":
        name_emp = input("Enter the name of employee: ")
        num_emp = input("enter the 4 digit number of the employee: ")
        employees[name_emp] = num_emp
        continue

    if text == "b":
        del_emp = input("Enter the name of the empoyee to be removed: ")
        del employees[del_emp]
        continue

    if text == "c":
        find_emp = input("Enter the name of the employee to be searched: ")
        if(find_emp in employees):
            print(find_emp,"'s number is", employees[find_emp])
            continue
        else:
            print ("NOT FOUND")
            continue

    if text == "d":
        print("Current Directory")
        print()
        print(employees)
        continue

    if text == "q":
        break

    else:
        print("Invalid Selection")
        continue
```

Initially, I am having trouble to match upper case and lower case letters for the text input selection, until i added the str.lower function on the input strings and on my "if" statements, I change the match to lower case letters. IN this case if I enter "a" and "A" or b" and "B" it works fine.

Also, before that,  my if statements match "A" and this program is not working. It keeps matching the last statement which is on the "else" part.

I would like to know how the str.lower behaves in this case and why I need to match a lower case string on my if statement? Is it because this method automatically converts the string to lower case?

Comment: Your `if`s would better serve you as `elif`

Comment: Yep, @matisetorm. Your cases are mutual exclusive.

Comment: Just to explain a bit further. There is nothing wrong with lower(). Rather, the whole script goes through all the options, and the final if/else (checking if "q") always fires. Since on any other condition, "q" is false, the else condition fires

Comment: I got it guys!!! Sorry :-)

Comment: Side-note: `while text != "q" or "quit":` is wrong (and effectively an infinite loop if not for the later test for `text == "q"` that `break`s, because whether or not `text != "q"` passes, `or "quit"` guarantees a truthy result; all non-empty strings are truthy). You want `while text not in ("q", "quit"):`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with lower(). Rather, the whole script goes through all the options, and the final if/else (checking if "q") always fires. Since on any other condition, "q" is false, the else condition fires

You should be using elif statements.

The correct code is:

```
if text == "a":
    name_emp = input("Enter the name of employee: ")
    num_emp = input("enter the 4 digit number of the employee: ")
    employees[name_emp] = num_emp

elif text == "b":
    del_emp = input("Enter the name of the empoyee to be removed: ")
    del employees[del_emp]

elif text == "c":
    find_emp = input("Enter the name of the employee to be searched: ")
    if(find_emp in employees):
        print(find_emp,"'s number is", employees[find_emp])
    else:
        print ("NOT FOUND")

elif text == "d":
    print("Current Directory")
    print()
    print(employees)

elif text == "q":
    break

else:
    print("Invalid Selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a formating problem in your question as the loop does not show in the code block.

I understand you use this in a while loop, managing the exclusive condition with a `continue` statement in every `if` which some of the answers didn't notice.

It is better not to delegate on the loop the management of the exclusive conditions of the `if` statement.

Also, don't use `str.lower("A string")` but `A string".lower()`. Both do the same but the former is a call to the class function passing a parameter to the self attribute and the latter is a call to the string object method (without any parameter). Both returns the string in lowercase so "a string", but objects should be used with their methods, not the class methods. Because reasons.

So your the input function returns a string which is converted to lowercase before being assigned to the text variable. That variable should match one of your cases.

Comment: Thank you for the notes! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was the `if/elif`, but I think another opportunity for improvement exists in restructuring the code a little.

This solution helps break the code into more testable chunks with fewer responsibilities, which is always nice.

This is using a dictionary to dispatch methods, which is one of the (many!) cool things you can do with first class functions. This could be further enhanced to reduce the amount of work happening in the while loop, but I think it might be a step in the right direction as it is.

```
def add_employee(employees):
    name_emp = input("Enter the name of employee: ")
    num_emp = input("enter the 4 digit number of the employee: ")
    employees[name_emp] = num_emp

def remove_employee(employees):
    del_emp = input("Enter the name of the empoyee to be removed: ")
    del employees[del_emp]

def find_employee(employees):
    find_emp = input("Enter the name of the employee to be searched: ")
    if(find_emp in employees):
        print(find_emp,"'s number is", employees[find_emp])
    else:
        print ("NOT FOUND")

def display_directory(employees):
    print("Current Directory")
    print()
    print(employees)

text = str("")
while text not in ("q" or "quit"):
    print 

    print("             Select from the following menu")
    print("             A. Add Employee")
    print("             B. Remove Employee")
    print("             C. Find Employee")
    print("             D. Display the current directory")
    print("             Q. Quit")
    text = str.lower(input("Enter your selection: "))
    print("Current selection is ", text)

    options = {
        'a' : add_employee,
        'b' : remove_employee,
        'c' : find_employee,
        'd' : display_directory
    }

    if text == "q":
        break
    else:
        if text in options:
            options[text](employees)
        else:
            print("Invalid Selection")

        continue
```

Comment: this is cool! yes, I agree that using functions may help to reduce clutter and understand the program. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It has to be : `input("Enter your selection: ").lower()`

`lower()` is a function of string and to return `lowercase()` of that string, it does not need to provide any parameters. Although, this is just semantic and unhelpful.

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't _have_ to be `input("Enter your selection: ").lower()`. `str.lower(input("Enter your selection: "))` works as well - albeit it's more cumbersome.